# Decoding Image from Protobuf using Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have an image that I have encoded and sent out using protobuf like so:

```
message.image = numpy.ndarray.tobytes(image)
```

when I receive and parse that message I use this:

```
image_array = numpy.frombuffer(request.image, numpy.uint8)
```

This gives me a one-dimensional array. I cannot get this back into an image format. I have tried using numpy's reshape command like so but with no luck:

```
image = image_array.reshape( 400, 600, 3 )
```

The image being sent is 400x600 pixels and it is a 3 channel color image. Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried using `np.reshape` ?

Comment: I have but with no luck, I have added the reshape command I used to the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would also need to store the `img.shape` data of the original image you wanted to encode and whole decoding you need that `img.shape` value to reshape the matrix to it's original form as:

```
import numpy as np

# Create a dummy matrix
img = np.ones((50, 50, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
# Save the shape of original matrix.
img_shape = img.shape

message_image = np.ndarray.tobytes(img)

re_img = np.frombuffer(message_image, dtype=np.uint8)

# Convert back the data to original image shape.
re_img = np.reshape(re_img, img_shape)
```

Comment: That is what I did with the image_array.reshape( 400, 600, 3 ) the 400,600,3 is the output of image.shape I had just hard coded to to ensure it worked

Comment: image_array.reshape(600, 600, 3) is different from image_array.reshape((600, 600, 3)). Try with the former one

Comment: Thanks! That gets me to an image that is the right width and height but now it is displaying as all gray but when I print the data from the arrays to the console they are the same before and after transmitting.